# Making a Android Toast via JNI, i.e. calling Java methods via JNI

Tags: c++, android, java

Concerning the outputting of an `Toast`, I found that there are some ways to make a `Toast`, that invoke calling a `FindClass` on `JNIEnv` object with the `android/widget/Toast` parameter, but I found no references in the code doing this.

I found this code [here](https://github.com/demuyan/AndroidNDKbook/blob/master/ch02/JniToast/jni/jnitoast.c)

```
jclass toast = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/widget/Toast");
// ToastクラスのmakeTextスタティックメソッドのメソッドIDを取得する
jmethodID methodMakeText = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, toast, "makeText", "(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;");
if(methodMakeText == NULL){
LOGE("toast.makeText not Found");

return;
```

But when using the `strings` tool on the C++ compiled files used in the app I'm decompiling, I haven't found any references to a `Toast`.

What other ways there are to call methods in a Java library, e.g. make a Toast?

Comment: Does your app have java components?

Comment: @sudhackar , yes

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
jclass toast = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/widget/Toast"); // get the class you need (need to be already loaded otherwise you have to define it first)
jmethodID methodToCall = env->GetStaticMethodID(toast, "makeText", "(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;"); // get your desidered method

env->CallStaticVoidMethod(toast, methodToCall, <your parameters here>); // ask the jvm to call your method (assuming its static)
```

Comment: I just posted this code in my answer.. Thank you for your contribution though. Helping me explore options beyond this one and its implementations would've helped me more.

Comment: well i actually dont think there are more options.. atleast i never seen something different to call a method via jni

Comment: That is the point. The app is displaying the toast in a very obscure manner

Comment: Maybe reflections via jni?